# Remove small protrusions from line using python Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to Image processing, I want to remove the small protrusions from the line that is on the below image. Can someone help me to do that?

[image]

Comment: Using a median blur will smooth the edges while maintaining the sharpness.

Comment: looks like a nearest neighbor resampling of a source picture. post that maybe, and the code that produced this picture. -- erosion/dilation/opening/closing might do the trick

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.